# Developing using docker-compose

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I have .NET Core app which contain ClientApp folder with Angular code. When I locally run my app without docker I use

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
 {
     app.UseSpa(spa =>
     {
         // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
         // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

         spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
         spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200/");
     });
 }
```

to redirect request to Angular app. When I changed something in Angular I don't need to rebuild my .NET Core app and my changes will be applied automatically.

Right now I created docker-compose file which spin up all my apps in Docker. How can I setup that staff for not rebuild manually my app image after made changes in fronted or backend part? How to make this automatically?
Does map local folder with Angular to container is the best solution?

```
volumes:
      - ./PathToLocalAngularApp:/app/ClientApp
```

If yes, can I use the same approach for backend part?